# Float não funciona corretamente e sobrepõem section

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema em uma `section` pois o texto de uma delas esta sobrepondo  o outro quando a página e redimencionada e não sei mais oque tentar para isso não acontecer segue o código :

```css
/**********************************************************************************

        Section-2

***********************************************************************************/

.sessao-2 {
  height: 450px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}
.bg-sessao2 {
  background-image: url(https://clicksem.net/images/background_electronica.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -2;
}
#bg-section {
  background-image: url(../images/overlay.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.texto-sessao2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.texto-sessao2 h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
.texto-sessao2 p {
  /*width: 40%;*/
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -3%;
}
#btn-sessao2 li {
  display: inline;
}
#btn-sessao2 li a {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
#btn-sessao2 li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
}
/**********************************************************************************

        Section-3

***********************************************************************************/

.sessao-3 {
  height: 450px;
}
.bg-sessao3 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -2;
}
#web-design {
  width: 550px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  float: left;
}
.texto-sessao-3 {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}
.texto-sessao-3 h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
.texto-sessao-3 p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: -3%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
#contato {
  color: #222;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
#contato:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
/**********************************************************************************

        Section-4

***********************************************************************************/

.sessao-4 {
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.bg-sessao-4 {
  background-image: url(https://clicksem.net/images/background_electronica.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -2;
}
#bg-section-4 {
  background-image: url(../images/overlay.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.texto-sessao-4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: gabriola;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
.texto-sessao-4 h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
.texto-sessao-4 p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: -3%;
}
#sobre {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
#sobre:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<section class="sessao-2">
  <div id="bg-section">
    <div class="texto-sessao2">
      <h1>Um mundo de posibilidades</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo .</p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <ul id="btn-sessao2">
      <li><a href="#">Conheça nossos serviços</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-sessao2"></div>
</section>

<section class="sessao-3">
  <div class="bg-sessao3">

    <img src="http://blog.dudamobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Viewing-platforms.png" alt="web-design" id="web-design" />

    <section class="section--blue wow fadeInRight" data-wow-offset="300">
      <div class="texto-sessao-3">
        <h1>Porque nos esolher?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo .</p>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" id="contato">Quem somos</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="sessao-4">
  <div id="bg-section-4">

    <div class="texto-sessao-4">
      <h1>Pode contar conosco sempre</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo .</p>
      <br/>
      <a href="#" id="sobre">sobre a web sky's</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-sessao-4"></div>
</section>
```

a parte que esta com problema seria a que esta no meio onde esta o título porque nos escolher se redimencionar a tela vocês verão que essa `section` sobrepõem a de baixo oque estou fazendo de errado segue uma imagem para poder visualizar como ela fica na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando redimenciono a tela ela fica assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é porque deviam estar a ser usadas `media queries` para ecrãs de menor resolução para remover atributos como: `position:absolute;`, `float:left/right;` e alturas como por exemplo `height:450px;` que fazem com que o conteúdo e as `divs` fiquem todas umas por cima das outras.

O HTML também pode ser melhorado, e a implementação de imagens como `backgrounds` pode ser melhorada apontando-os de forma correcta para a própria `section` que queres que tenha uma imagem como background, em vez de criares novas classes e adicionares a estas `position:absolute;` e `z-index:-2;` etc...

Eu estive a melhorar o teu código HTML e CSS, mas apenas melhorei-o com base em pequenas resoluções:

> **Aqui tens o código aprimorado: http://jsfiddle.net/uepa1avt/**

Depois se quiseres voltar a aplicar os valores `float:left;` ou `float:right` para que as `divs` fiquem do lado esquerdo ou direito como tinhas antigamente no teu código apenas para telas de grandes resoluções, podes fazê-lo adicionando `media queries` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
/* Este código é aplicado em todo o tipo de resoluções */
.texto-sessao-3 {
    float: right;
}

/* Mas quando a resolução é menor que 700px, este código é aplicado em vez disso */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .texto-sessao-3 {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

> **Exemplo no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uepa1avt/1/**

Comment: deu certo amigo obrigado pela ajuda